# How to avoid displaying the dialog for choice of webcam

Tags: c#, wpf, webcam

How can I avoid displaying the dialog for the choice of webcam.

After about 18 hours I have gotten my webcam to run (I'm sure many more cameras will work) from my application in WPF.

No DirectShowNet, No WPFMediaKit, No WIA

I adapted the code of an implementation with avicap32. It works "perfectly" but always displays the dialog box of the device of choice and I want to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think this behavior is by design, so the user always knows when an application is trying to access it. Nobody wants and application that takes a photo of you with out your permission. In Win8 the user can override this behavior per-application.

Comment: Well... maybe the answer you are looking for is: No, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

I only found this maybe it will help you.

```
SendMessage(_windowHandle, WM_CAP_CONNECT, _videoSourceIndex, 0)
```

Maybe you should ask this guy:
[C# web cam WM_CAP_CONNECT: Want to force a capture source when multiple capture sources present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847659/c-sharp-web-cam-wm-cap-connect-want-to-force-a-capture-source-when-multiple-cap)